# Loading a .mbtiles map overlays everything with black (as of QGIS 2.16)

Tags: qgis, raster, mbtiles, qgis-2.16

I've been having a frustrating problem with QGIS lately. When I load a raster map with .mbtiles extension in QGIS 2.16, it overlays the whole workspace with black pixels (refer to the attached images).

I tried adding 0 (zero) to "Additional no data value" and it does make the black go away, but at the same time makes the colors in the raster map sort of washed out.

For some reason the new version of QGIS does not properly handle these maps.

Any solutions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If it worked in previous QGIS versions then it could be a bug. You could submit a [bug report](https://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis). In the meantime, hopefully others can provide a workaround :)